# Drag and Drop in Hammer.js?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, hammer.js

I'm working on a Tinder-remake. Just for a bit of practice.

I want to use Hammer.js with the Drag an Drop API but i can't figure out how to let it work. The recognizer works fine but when i'm including Drag and Drop i can't find to let it work.

```
const card = document.getElementById('card');
const hammertime = new Hammer(card);
hammertime.on('dragstart', (e) => {
  console.log('dragstart');
});

hammertime.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });
hammertime.on('swipe', async (eventObject) => {
  if (eventObject.angle < -90 || eventObject.angle > 90) {
    this.toggleLike();
    console.log('like');
  } else {
    this.toggleDislike();
    console.log('dislike');
  }
});`
```